# What is the most simple formula to achieve this pattern?

Tags: functions

Can the pattern in the attached diagram be captured by tuning a single parameter in a simple function? If so, what function is that?[image]

Comment: Note: The green line is linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
f_n(x)=\frac{\alpha\,}{1+\left(\frac{2x}{1-2x}\right)^n}
$$
For $\alpha=1$ and $n=1,2,3,4,5$, we get
[image]

Comment: Very beautiful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you scale and flip almost any [Cumulative Distribution Function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), you should get exactly what you're looking for. The simplest CDF is from the [Kumaraswamy Distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kumaraswamy_distribution), which has CDF $1-(1-x^a)^b$.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to construct the desired curve is to start with a [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function)
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp(A(x-1/4))}$$
where $A$ is a positive parameter that influences the steepness.

Add a line through $(1/4,0)$
$$g(x)=\alpha f(x)+\beta (x-1/4)$$
with $\beta$ to be determined such that the curve passes through $(0,\alpha)$ and $(1/2,0)$:
$$g(0)=\alpha \frac{1}{1+\exp(-A/4)}-\frac{\beta}{4}=\alpha$$
$$\implies 4 \alpha \left( \frac{1}{1+\exp(-A/4)}-1\right)=\beta$$

So 
$$\frac{\alpha}{1+\exp(A(x-1/4))}+4 \alpha \left( \frac{1}{1+\exp(-A/4)}-1\right)(x-1/4)$$
behaves as desired. (Note: at $A=0$ this function is exactly linear, in the $A\rightarrow \infty $ limit it becomes a step function)

[image]

It works just fine in Mathematica:

```
\[Alpha]/(1 + Exp[A*(x - 1/4)]) + 4*\[Alpha]*(1/(1 + Exp[-A/4]) - 1)*(x - 1/4)
{% /. {\[Alpha] -> 1, A -> 0}, % /. {\[Alpha] -> 1, A -> 20}, % /. {\[Alpha] -> 1, A -> 100}}
Plot[%, {x, 0, 1/2}]
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried to enter your formula in Mathematica, but I don't get your plots, except for A = 0. I am quite interested in getting your solution to work and I was inspired by the idea that perhaps the point of intersection (0,25, 1/2*alpha) can be made dynamic. For example, suppose I wished the intersect to be (0.4, 1/2 * alpha)...

Comment: @user120911, it works just fine in Mathematica, see the edit. (but note A has to be quite large, say 20 or 100)